# Нужно чтоб подложка следовала за активным пунктом

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/4j68tg7e/1/

Есть такая менюшка, получается 2 ряда, и там фоновая подложка которая двигается за активным пунктом, правда сейчас она очень некорректно работает. Двигается как угодно произвольно в любое место и только по горизонтали. Хотя там есть второй ряд, нужно чтоб вертикально также двигалась. Кто поможет решить чтоб горизонтально она корректно двигалась и по вертикали

```
var $marker = $('.select-bg-marker');
var $marker_item = $('.row-select .btn-select');
$marker.css({
    left: $marker_item.filter('.active').position().left,
    width: $marker_item.filter('.active').outerWidth(),
    height: $marker_item.filter('.active').outerHeight()
});
$marker_item.on('click', function() {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
        var left = $(this).position().left-$marker_item.filter('.active').position().left;
        $marker.css({
            'width': $(this).outerWidth(),
            'height': $(this).outerHeight(),
            'transform': 'translateX('+left+'px)'
        });
    }

    $marker_item.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переделанный пример:

```js
var $marker = $('.select-bg-marker');
var $marker_item = $('.row-select .btn-select');
$marker.css({
  left: $marker_item.filter('.active').position().left,
  width: $marker_item.filter('.active').outerWidth(),
  height: $marker_item.filter('.active').outerHeight()
});
$marker_item.on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
    var marker = $(this)
    var {
      left,
      top
    } = marker.position()

    $marker.css({
      'width': marker.outerWidth(),
      'height': marker.outerHeight(),
      'transform': `translate(${left}px, ${top}px)`,
    });
  }

  $marker_item.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.calc__platform {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.select-bg-marker {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #264c7a;
  height: 38px;
  min-width: 50px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  transition: .3s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.row-select {
  border: 1px solid #264c7a;
  -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.row-select:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.btn-select {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 33.3%;
}

.btn-select span {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 36px;
  color: #010101;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -o-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.btn-select.active span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calc__platform">
  <div class="select-bg-marker"></div>
  <div class="row-select">
    <label class="btn btn-select active">
      <input type="radio" name="platform" hidden checked>
      <span>Xeon-E5</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-select">
      <input type="radio" name="platform" hidden>
      <span>Xeon-E5v3</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-select">
      <input type="radio" name="platform" hidden>
      <span>Xeon-5620</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="row-select">
    <label class="btn btn-select">
      <input type="radio" name="platform" hidden>
      <span>Scalable</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-select">
      <input type="radio" name="platform" hidden>
      <span>Xeon-E3v5</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-select">
      <input type="radio" name="platform" hidden>
      <span>Xeon-E3</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Обновлен обработчик клика:

```
$marker_item.on('click', function() {
    if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
            var marker = $(this)
        var { left, top } = marker.position()

        $marker.css({
            'width': marker.outerWidth(),
            'height': marker.outerHeight(),
            'transform': `translate(${left}px, ${top}px)`,
        });
    }

    $marker_item.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

});
```

Comment: Казалось бы просто, зато стало работать как надо. Благодарю!